# Backup copy from iCloud shows error cloud provider is not running when VPN is turned on

Tags: backup, script, icloud, nordvpn

I've made a backup script which (amongst other operations) copies my iCloud photos directory to a separate location. This script will run every time I log in to my computer.

Some time ago I purchased a NordVPN subscription. NordVPN starts as I start my computer, and suddenly I noticed that this part of my backup failed: as soon as a new image is downloaded from iCloud, I get the error "cloud provider is not running" together with errorcode 0x0000016A. Then a timeout of 30 seconds follows, and the process repeats forever.

I've managed to figure out what was happening after a lot of Googling and trial/error, after which all was well and running just fine.

Scroll forward until a few weeks ago when I had some problems with my VPN, after which I removed the installation and reinstalled the software from scratch. Obviously, the problem manifested itself again, and the easiest solution would be to reconfigure the VPN as I had before...

... but I failed to write down the changes I had made to my VPN, and I cannot find the sources of information I found when I initially had the problem.

I've tried split tunneling and listed just about each and any program even remotely related to iCloud, and I've tried messing with the different VPN protocol settings, but so far I've not found the solution (again).

Does anybody know what I need to change in order to make iCloud downloads work again through NordVPN? If I remember correctly, this problem was not specifically a NordVPN problem, rather a problem for all VPNs, and had to do with the fact that iCloud didn't trust the IP accessing the cloud (as it didn't recognize you as being the person downloading from your cloud account)...

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but consider that, to the iCloud service, your communication is coming from the NordVPN host, with a different I{P address from yours, and likely in another country. You'd need to set up the iCloud account *with VPN running*. Alternatively, create a split connection, with iCloud **not** behind VPN: https://nordvpn.com/features/split-tunneling/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I think the first solution isn't an option, as I will get a new IP address each time I log in to my computer. NordVPN provides me with a server within my country, but not necessarily the same one each time.
I've enabled split tunneling for iCloud, but that is exactly my problem: I already have added each and every process I can find to split tunneling (so they don't use the VPN), but it still doesn't work. This means that I've missed some process which I had in my previous setup, but I can't figure out which one...
Thanks for  your reply though!